# Select and Join method

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to use join method connecting several tables together and select some variables out, but it shows me that n.DateOfShipping and n.ProductName, these two do not exist in current context. I got the error CS1061.

```
    var newestOrder = orderProducts.Where(op => op.DateOfShipping >= Today).
                    Join(products, op => op.ProductId, pr => pr.Id, (op, pr) => new { pr.ProductName, op.DateOfShipping, op.OrderId }).
                    Join(orders, op => op.OrderId, o => o.Id, (op, o) => new { op.DateOfShipping, op.OrderId, o.ClientId }).
                    Join(clients, o => o.ClientId, cl => cl.Id, (o, cl) => new { cl.ClientName});
    foreach (var n in newestOrder){
       Console.WriteLine("Date of shipping: {0}, Product Name: {1}, Client Name: {2}", n.DateOfShipping, n.ProductName, n.ClientName);
    }
```

This is how its supposed to be like in query form.

```
 var newestOrders = from op in orderProducts
                                join pr in products on op.ProductId equals pr.Id
                                join o in orders on op.OrderId equals o.Id
                                join c in clients on o.ClientId equals c.Id

                                where op.DateOfShipping > today
                                orderby op.DateOfShipping
                                select new
                                {
                                    op.DateOfShipping,
                                    pr.ProductName,
                                    c.ClientName
                                };

             foreach (var n in newestOrders)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("Date of shipping: {0}, Product Name: {1}, Client Name: {2}", n.DateOfShipping, n.ProductName,n.ClientName);
             }
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You want to join on Id for every thing..  Products has both Id and ProductId.  Orders has both Id and OrderId.  Client as both Id and ClientId.  Do not join using ProductId, OrderId, and ClientId.

Comment: Actually ProductId, ClientId and OrderId are properties of OrderProduct while Order, Client and Product all have a property called Id. I just want to join them together then select those I need.

Comment: "something wrong with join" - wdym? Whats wrong? Note, all those joins are inner joins by default. So, as soon as there is no record in one table, you will not see the item in a resulting set.

Comment: Does this mean I can only join other tables with the table that I am currently dealing with?

Comment: It's good that you have included your sample code.  But you must always explain what you mean by "something wrong" or "it didn't work."    Does it fail to compile?--Show us the compile error.  Does it throw an exception at run time?--Show us the exception.  Does it run but give unexpected results?--Show us the results you get.    In the latter case, you might also need to provide sample data for each of the tables, so somebody can try to reproduce your error.

Comment: Sorry about that. It was the join. It didn't give me those variables that I want. errors occurs when I tried to print the result, It shows me that n.DateOfShipping, n.ProductName these two do not exist in current context.

Comment: So, you should edit the question to say something like this:  "When I try to compile this code, I get the following error:  CS001234; property does not exist......"  (or whatever the actual error was).

Comment: @TianxingWu please update your question (using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54929689/edit) link rather than clarifying it in the comments, because it makes the question clearer and not everyone will read through all the comments.

Comment: @Richard II I have edited that. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to carry on the fields you needed:

```
 var newestOrder = orderProducts.Where(op => op.DateOfShipping >= Today)
                   .Join(products, op => op.ProductId, pr => pr.Id, (op, pr) => new { pr.ProductName, op.DateOfShipping, op.OrderId })
                   .Join(orders, op => op.OrderId, o => o.Id, (op, o) => new { op.ProductName, op.DateOfShipping, o.ClientId }).
                    Join(clients, o => o.ClientId, cl => cl.Id, (o, cl) => new { o.ProductName, o.DateOfShipping, cl.ClientName});

    foreach (var n in newestOrder){
       Console.WriteLine("Date of shipping: {0}, Product Name: {1}, Client Name: {2}", n.DateOfShipping, n.ProductName, n.ClientName);
    }
```

after every join you have to select all the field you need in the next joind AND in the final extraction.